# Pass arguments to `python -c`

Tags: python

How can arguments be passed to the command line invocation of `python`?   Using `sys.argv` had this interesting [but not helpful] result:

```
echo "a b c" | python -c "import sys; 
             print([[str(x),a] for x,a in enumerate(sys.argv)])"
[['0', '-c']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the arguments after the `-c` option.

```
python -c "import sys; 
             print([[str(x),a] for x,a in enumerate(sys.argv)])" a b c
```

The pipe sends the strings to the scripts standard input, not arguments.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing in the code snippet here is putting `a b c` in the *standard input* to `python`. You can access this with `input()` to read a line, for instance:

```bash
echo 'my input' | python -c 'print("first line of standard input is: ", input())'
```

prints `my input`.

You can add arguments by putting them after your code, for instance:

```bash
python -c "import sys;print(sys.argv)" arg1 arg2 arg3
```

prints `["-c", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]`.

The first element in `sys.argv` is usually the file that was run to start the program (eg. "main.py"), but here it is "-c" since code was passed as a command-line argument.

Answer (score 1):

In case `echo "a b c"` stands for something more sophisticated than just `echo`, you can pass the output of any program as command line arguments of another program via backticks:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" `echo "a b c"`
['-c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Please don't advocate the archaic backtick form of command substitution, use `$(...)`

Comment: @Barmar Backticks are legally not deprecated, so it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Yes, not deprecated. But the new syntax has so much going for it that there's no good reason to keep using it.

Comment: Feel free to do whatever you want in your own code, I'm just suggesting that you not promote it here.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're using the `-c` option to provide inline code to execute. However, the inline code is considered as a single argument (`sys.argv[0]`), and any additional arguments are not passed correctly.

To pass arguments to the command line invocation of Python, you can modify your approach as follows:

```
echo "a b c" | python -c "import sys; 
args = sys.stdin.read().split()  # Read input from stdin and split into arguments
print([[str(x), a] for x, a in enumerate([sys.argv[0]] + args)])"
```